# Select "All" class elements before a if/else statement

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a field verification clause before initializing Googles reCAPTCHA and I'm running into a bit of a problem.

I can check if a element has a value by it's ID, however I can't seem to get by CLASS working. I basically want to execute the recaptcha if all fields with the class REQUIRED are filled in.

By ID, this works for only one question.

```
function validate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (!document.getElementById('q1').value) {
    alert("You must enter text into the required fields!");
} else {
    grecaptcha.execute();
}
```

By CLASS, not working :(

```
function validate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].value) {
        alert("You must enter text into the required fields!"); 
    } else {
        grecaptcha.execute();
    }
}
```

I've never done anything like this before, so any insight on a solution would be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: You're checking if nothing exists in the value -> `if (!questions[i].value)`?

Comment: You also are only checking the first, if that is valid, than it will submit, it would ignore the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're calling `grecaptcha.execute` *repeatedly*, once for every valid field (even if other fields are not valid).
2. You're checking `questions[i].value` which will be falsy if blank and truthy is not blank, but then treating truthy as blank.

Instead, just remember whether you've found any invalid ones and then issue an error or execute it (and add `!` to the check):

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
var valid = true;
for (var i=0; valid && i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (!questions[i].value) {
        valid = false;
    }
}
if (valid) {
    grecaptcha.execute();
} else {
    alert("You must enter text into the required fields!"); 
}
```

---

Side note: Your current check for empty fields will accept fields with only spaces in them. If you want to weed those out as well, use `trim` (on any vaguely-modern browser, and you can polyfill it for obsolete ones like IE8):

```
if (!questions[i].value.trim()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If one element is right, it executes the recaptcha. You want to check if *all* are right:

```
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
    for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
        if (questions[i].value && question[i].value!=="") {
           return alert("You must enter text into the required fields!"); 
        } 
    }
    grecaptcha.execute();
}
```